# Dot JKS (.jks file) is not found when cloning from Git

Tags: android, react-native, jks

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.

> Keystore file 'C:\MobileAppNewUI\speetar-react-native\android\app\mobile-app.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 0):

If I manually download .jks file from Git and paste it in my android/app folder, it works.